# Facebook Graph API - getting individual wall posts of a day

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph Explorer and trying to fetch each individual wall post my friends sent to me on a specific day (my birthday).

My request is for the feed:
https://graph.facebook.com/100000015733365/feed?access_token=xyz&since=7+October+2015

response:

```
    {
    "data": [
    {
        "id": "<post_id_2>",
        "from": {
            "name": "<name2>",
            "id": "<id2>"
        },
        "story": "<name2> and 69 others wrote on your timeline.",
        "story_tags": {
        "0": [
            {
                "id": "<id2>",
                "name": "<name2>",
                "type": "user",
                "offset": 0,
                "length": 8
            }
            ],
            "37": [
            {
                "id": "<my_id>",
                "name": "<my_name>",
                "type": "user",
                "offset": 37,
                "length": 8
            }
            ],
            "13": [
            {
                "id": "<id3>",
                "name": "<name3>",
                "type": "user",
                "offset": 13,
                "length": 9
            },
            {
                "id": "<id4>",
                "name": "<name4>",
                "type": "user",
                "offset": 13,
                "length": 9
            },
            {
                "id": "<id5>",
                "name": "<name5>",
                "type": "user",
                "offset": 13,
                "length": 9
            }
            ]
        },
        "privacy": {
        "value": "",
        "description": "",
        "friends": "",
        "allow": "",
        "deny": ""
        },
        "type": "status",
        "status_type": "wall_post",
        "created_time": "2015-10-07T20:43:07+0000",
        "updated_time": "2015-10-07T20:43:07+0000",
        "is_hidden": false,
        "is_expired": false
    }
```

It seems Facebook groups the posts by content, it's okay on my wall (in web browser) but how can I turn off this behavior through the API call? 
I cannot find any setting related to this even after I read the API reference thoroughly.

I need these grouped posts one by one because I would like to process them in python, since I cannot achieve this with the graph explorer I think it's okay to not post python code right now.

An alternative would be to expand this 'story' into a list of individual posts but this is well hidden according to the documentation.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think is possible. This post are automatically merged into one.

Comment: hi , I am facing exact same problem. Can you solve it please :(

Comment: I haven't found a solution, unfortunately :(

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Please help if anybody have any idea.